# Need to create one derieved column using existing two columns in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table customers which has 3 columns: shipping_date, end_date_offset_duration, offset duration.

Sample value for

- Shipping_date: 1/25/1999, 4/10/1998, 2/10/2007 ... ...
- end_date_offset_duration: 39, 450, 54 ..... ....
- offset duration: MONTH, DAY

Now need to create a third column named "WarrantyEndDate", which value will be derived like (shipping_date + end_date_offset_duration)=WarrantyEndDate which
will be in date format.

My issue is like end_date_offset_duration value sometimes it will refer as total no of days and sometimes will refer as total no of months.

So, now How i can create a query, which will give value of "WarrantyEndDate".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when offset_duration = 'MONTH'
             then add_months(shipping_date, end_date_offset_duration)
             else shipping_date + end_date_offset_duration
        end) as WarrantyEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `case when`:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN OFFSET_DURATION = 'MONTH' THEN ADD_MONTHS(SHIPPING_DATE, END_DATE_OFFSET_DURATION)
        WHEN OFFSET_DURATION = 'DAY'   THEN SHIPPING_DATE + END_DATE_OFFSET_DURATION
        ELSE SHIPPING_DATE -- NOT NEEDED IN YOUR CASE BUT ADDED FOR COMPLETENESS
    END AS WARRANTYENDDATE
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE
```

Cheers!!